# How to retrieve Blob Images from mysql database to a <img> tag using Java EE?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee

I tried a lot upon this problem but I didn't get a perfect solution. Only I want is to read an image which is saved in Blob format in the MySql database, within a jsp file.

That means I want to show up the picture inside a img HTML tag. How can I do that? How can I give a specific URL to src attribute?

Comment: You need another endpoint in your application that can serve up the raw image data with the appropriate MIME type in the headers.

Comment: Actually I didn't get what you said! Can you explain it little bit?

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).